# Custom error handling no longer works after upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-5

We use `config.exceptions_app` to route exceptions to a customer error controller (described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq/rails-3-2-error-handling-with-exceptions_app)). This has worked great in our Rails 4 app, but since we upgraded to Rails 5 this set up no longer works, and we get the error "undefined local variable or method `env'" in the handling function.

**application.rb**

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Route errors to our custom error controller
    # (See https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq)
    config.exceptions_app = lambda do |env|
      ExceptionsController.action(:render_error).call(env)
    end

  end
end
```

**exceptions_controller.rb**

```
class ExceptionsController < BaseController

  def render_error

    @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"] # RAILS 5 RAISES ERROR HERE: "undefined local variable or method `env'"
    exception_wrapper = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(request.env, @exception)
    @status_code = exception_wrapper.status_code
    trace = exception_wrapper.application_trace

    # Custom notifications and stuff...

  end

end
```

Comment: "env has been deprecated in favour of request.env for Rails5."  Can you try his suggestion from another post?  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143732/richard-peck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @zakariah1 for the help (if you want to post an answer I'll give you cred).

Turns out I had to make a couple of changes to the render_error function to get everything working. I've posted the Rails 4 and Rails 5 versions below for reference:

```
def render_error

  # --- FOR RAILS 4: ---
  ## @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
  ## exception_wrapper = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception)

  # --- FOR RAILS 5: ---
  @exception = request.env["action_dispatch.exception"]
  exception_wrapper = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(request.env['action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner'], @exception)

  trace = exception_wrapper.application_trace

  # Custom notifications and stuff...

end
```